# Terminal Bash - regex not matching

Tags: bash

I am using Dropbox Uploader and I'm able to produce a list of files which the below outputs as `$line`. I want to partially match certain files but I cannot get this regex to work. I have tried it in regexr.com which it works but the use case doesn't

```
./dropbox_uploader.sh list | while read line
do
        if [[ $line =~ /person_(.*}?).sql/g ]];
        then
                echo "match";
        else
                echo "no match";
        fi
#echo "$line"
done
```

Current output of `$list`

```
> Listing "/"... DONE
[F] 168953708 person_02-15-2017_21-01-42.sql
[F] 170024815 person_02-17-2017_11-42-01.sql
[F] 170012760 person_02-17-2017_12-00-02.sql
```

Expected output of above

```
person_02-15-2017_21-01-42.sql
person_02-17-2017_11-42-01.sql
person_02-17-2017_12-00-02.sql
```

I essentially am trying to match the line which has the filename and output just that filename.

Comment: Your expected output? for your input?

Comment: @Inian updated original post

Comment: Nobody underlined why your regex didn't work, so here it goes : the `/pattern/flags` construct doesn't exist in `bash` (nor in most languages actually). It's the use of the `=~` operator that specifies that what follows is a regex pattern. Writing `[[ "[F] 168953708 person_02-15-2017_21-01-42.sql" =~ person_(.*}?).sql ]] && echo match || echo no match` would have worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking for a more robust regex way to do this in `bash`, do

```
while IFS= read -r line
do
    if [[ $line =~ .*person_([[:alnum:]|_|-]+)\.sql ]]; then
        printf "person_%s.sql\n" "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
    fi
done <file
```

produces a result as

```
person_02-15-2017_21-01-42.sql
person_02-17-2017_11-42-01.sql
person_02-17-2017_12-00-02.sql
```

Answer (score 1):

Your regular expression is broken but I would suggest that you don't need one:

```
./dropbox_uploader.sh list | while read -r tag size file; do
    if [[ $file = person* ]]; then
        # do something with "$file"
    fi
done
```

This assumes that the filename always starts at the third field in the output and that you haven't used any newlines in your filenames.

You could make the glob pattern more specific if necessary, e.g. by changing `person*` to `person*.sql`.

Comment: IMHO, this does not check the pattern is ending with .sql

Comment: @Inian true, I've edited to mention making the glob more specific if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

> I essentially am trying to match the line which has the filename and output just that filename.

So, you need nothing more than this (if your filenames don’t contain spaces):

```
./dropbox_uploader.sh list | awk '/person_.*}?\.sql/{print $3}'
```

I’ve kept the optional final `}` in your regexp, but I really don’t see its reason, because `.` would match it. Omitting `}?` would produce exactly the same results.

The regexp you were trying to match in bash didn’t work because bash doesn’t use the `/` delimiter nor the `g` modifier.